# Managed Package Tab not working in Community

Tags: managed-package, community-builder, tab, customer-community-plus

I installed a managed package in one of the org and trying to show a tab from managed package in community. When i click the tab i am seeing the following screen.

[image]

This is happening for tabs from Managed package. I gave Read,Edit and Create access for that object to Customer Community User profile. Is it possible to show managed package tabs in community? or am i missing any settings for managed package.

Comment: What is a licensing model of the package? Did you grant license to the package to community user?

Comment: @kurunve, Thanks for your reply. I dont know but I can check i have access to Developer Org. Can you guide me how to check that.

Comment: This link could help - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=distribution_package_user_licenses.htm&type=5